# Capturing video on iOS: what is the difference between capturing video using AVMovieFileOutput or AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am following [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/) tutorial on how to capture video on iOS.

When you download their sample code and run it, it shows two methods of capturing video, using `AVMovieFileOutput` and using `AVAssetWriter`.

What is the technical difference between the two methods? is one better than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `AVMovieFileOutput` and `AVAssetWriter` (in conjunction with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`) allow you to capture media samples to files, but `AVAssetWriter` is the lower level and more configurable<sup>*</sup> of the two interfaces, so with `AVAssetWriter` / `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` you can intercept and modify media samples before they are written which allows you to apply effects, and stream off the device, etc.

Last time I checked you couldn't add both `AVMovieFileOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to an iOS capture session, so as soon as you want to examine *and* record the data flowing through the session in real time, you have no choice but to use `AVAssetWriter` / `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

<sup>*</sup>in fact `AVMovieFileOutput` is probably implemented *using* `AVAssetWriter`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was suspecting AVAssetWriter was the most powerful but was not sure about it. THANKS!!!